# Non-touchable seek bar but showing progress

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm making a simple app for timing. It has a seek bar to set the time and a button to start or stop. It plays a short sound effect when the time's up. Almost everything is done but this, when the timer counts down, I would like the seek bar to keep track of the time, meaning the little dot on it moving backward as the timer counts.  Of course the issue can be solved by using the listener but I want to make the seek bar non-touchable when the timer is counting but it still shows progress.  Thank you for reading this, hope you have an answer for me.

Comment: [check this ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21330383/2794507)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) because it has useful information that will guide you in the right direction and provides detailed instructions explaining: [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer); [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); [how to present your problematic code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); [what questions belong here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what questions don't](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ProgressBar and set it to:

```
  progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
```

Than you can update the progress by calling:

```
  progressBar.setProgress(progress);
```

This is the regular style:

```
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"      
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"      
    android:max="100" 
    />
```

If you want more sophisticated types of progressbar take a look here: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/76